# Delete User View named the same as system view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am exporting a database to Azure and have found a user view created in a previous version of MSSQL (Currently running 2008) that is name INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS which obviously should be impossible.  I can find the objectid in sysobjects but can find no way to drop the view by anything other than it's name.

Trying to drop the view this error is generated which makes sense:

> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1 Cannot drop the view
>   'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS', because it does not exist or
>   you do not have permission.

But the object in sysobjects and it's corresponding definition are definitely user based, not what one should expect.

Any thoughts?

Pics:
[image: Results of Drop View]
[image: Query Results]

Comment: Looks like someone probably did something like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/LRDTC.png (From The Guru's Guide to SQL Server) - I've no idea how you can clean it up now. Does connecting via the DAC help in any way?

Comment: Same results.  This database has been in use for over 15 years, upgraded from past versions of MSSQL, the link does seem probably of someone doing.

Comment: Does `exec sp_rename 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS', 'TABLE_CONSTRAINTS2'` have any better luck? or `ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`?

Comment: The problem is that even as sysadmin you can't mess with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  At least not that I've been able to tell. I'm going to try TF 1717 when I get home.

Comment: I've tried every variation of rename, but always get this err "Msg 15225, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 338
No item by the name of 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS' could be found in the current database 'XXX', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'."

Comment: My guess is that it was created prior to 2005 when it was possible modify the INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema.  I'm not sure you will be able to touch it at this point.

Comment: We are using SQL compare to move the data and exclude the view because it seems that there is no way to drop it.  Thanks much for everyone's thoughts and help.

Answer (score 1):

Making a guess with no information but is the name in `sys.objects` **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS**?

Try running this:

```
SELECT object_schema_name(object_id) AS SchemaName, name 
FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE name like '%TABLE_CONSTRAINTS'
```

I'm guessing you get something like this:

```
SchemaName          Name
------------------  ------------------------------------
INFORMATION_SCHEMA  TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
dbo                 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

First confirm that the second entry is actually a view then run the following:

```
DROP VIEW [dbo].[INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS]
```

---

Please run the following query and post a screenshot of the results in your question.

```
SELECT object_id, schema_id, object_schema_name(object_id) AS SchemaName, name, type
FROM sys.all_objects
WHERE name like '%TABLE_CONSTRAINTS'
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.

By running the first query I get the following results:

INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
Somehow a view was created with the same name as a system table and for me to move forward I need to remove it somehow.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I've modified the query slightly.  Please take a screenshot and add it to your query.

Comment: Sorry, can't get line breaks to work in the comments!

Comment: Yep.  That's why I was suggesting the screen shot.  Also we need the extra information.  Use the query at the bottom & re-do the screen shots :)

Comment: Just added.  Thanks much for looking at it.

Comment: No problem.  I'm going to add another column to the query.

Comment: Column added.  It seems like it should be possible having both named that.